# Table with 36 records join with table with 2,151,316 records

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle. My query run fast if I not join with a table with just 36 records. If I join then it takes nearly 2 seconds. Now I wanna improve query. Here is glimpse of query,

```
SELECT BT.Col1, Count('t') 
FROM BigTable BT
INNER JOIN  SmallTable ST ON ST.SomeCol = BT.SomeCol
GROUP BY BT.Col1
```

I also tested with EXISTS but the time remain same.

BigTable have 2,151,300 records and small 36 records.

Comment: Is BT.SomeCol indexed? Did you gather statistics?

Comment: Yes but still slow.

Comment: @Tomalak I just wanna make sure BT.Col1 exist in SmallTable

Comment: @Tomalak: Your queries will not return the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this index on BigTable:

```
CREATE INDEX big_covering_ix ON BigTable( SomeCol, Col1 );
```

---

I am not sure what is a purpose of the constant `t` here:

```
SELECT  ..... Count('t')
```

It would be simpler just: `Count(*)`.
Anyway, it does not affect the speed of the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing this as `exists` and then adding indexes.  The query is:

```
SELECT BT.Col1, Count(*) 
FROM BigTable BT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SmallTable ST WHERE ST.SomeCol = BT.SomeCol)
GROUP BY BT.Col1;
```

This assumes that `SmallTable` has no duplicates.

For this query, try an index on `BigTable(col1, somecol)`.